# 70728/2 Ninjago piece too short?

Tags: building, instructions, ninjago

My son is putting together the 70728 set and the grey tall pieces in book two at step 8 seem to be too short, they leave a gap. By about a mm. Has anyone else had this experience?

[image]

Comment: My first thought is: Is everything seated completely? It's amazing how fast tolerances can add up. One way to check those tall pieces is to get 5 regular bricks (anything of brick height) and stack them up and compare height to the seemingly problematic 1x2x5 light grey pieces, which should be equal.

Answer (score 2):

As this set is built on a plate-built base, it is quite possible that they are not pushed together tightly. I have ran into this numerous times when building the LEGO Modular Buildings as the second and third floors have a plate-built floor. Look through everything that has been built so far and make sure that the plates are pushed together all the way. LEGO does have some tolerance and viggle-room, but it is much less than a millimeter.